# Python - How to print out all json into a list

Tags: python, json

So im trying to make a script that makes requests on a website and after that it compares if there is new item added into the requests meaning if there is one - alert me, if there isnt any. requests the same page in few minutes.

So what im haivng issues now with is to actually print out to a list where it tells me:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

but whenever I print the element it just gives me a print of "id" which I can't understand the reason -

The code look:

```
   resp = s.get(url)



    list = []
    i = 0
    for element in resp.json()['threads']['product']:
        print(element) #<--- this gives me a print of "id"
        list.append(element['fullTitle'])
    #ERROR - list.append(element['fullTitle'])
    #TypeError: string indices must be integers
        i+=1

    print(list)

    while True:
        try:
            new_list = []
            url = 'https://hellowebsite.com'
            resp = s.get(url)

            for element in resp.json()['threads']['product']:
                new_list.append(element['fullTitle'])

            print(new_list)

            for link in new_list:
                if link not in list:
                    print('New item found! - ' + link)


            else:
                print("No new itemfound!")
                time.sleep(10)

        except:
            randomtime = random.randint(6, 12)
```

Json code: (its not fully completed but it looks like this)

```
{
    "country": "GB",
    "locale": "Thrill",
    "threads": [{
                "id": "f44291998750ce50301f36607c7996b5db5a9c3b",
                "interestId": "57d4d929-694c-4fdd-9277-f0df465cd7c7",
                "createdDate": "2018-06-26T08:05:24.000",
                "product": {
                    "id": "b0bfdaa1-140c-54de-b040-66854ec62d1b",
                    "interestId": "a53256c1-983b-43d5-895c-c5b7c3eedc85",
                    "colorCode": "100",
                    "fullTitle": "Item Number 1",
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "0c132053034f79c08dd474d6371875fe421e8694",
                "interestId": "ceb1c5f5-4ff2-43f4-8330-d537d1a4f5f9",
                "createdDate": "2018-06-26T08:24:42.000",
                "product": {
                    "id": "2b7830e3-2e36-54cd-a290-29c38493b290",
                    "interestId": "8aaeb398-91d6-45f1-b0d0-f4e8561e62fb",
                    "colorCode": "800",
                    "fullTitle": "Item Number 2",
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "985ff4b1bb969dd7a95ea589aff4d5f4710ab69e",
                "interestId": "aa73be8b-793e-4d78-b512-e80e2a019599",
                "createdDate": "2018-06-25T10:20:47.000",
                "product": {
                    "colorCode": "001",
                    "fullTitle": "Item number 3",

                }.....
```

What would be the suggestion to be able to print out all the fullTitle into a list and then continue to do the compare?

---

EDIT FULLTRACE

```
resp = s.get(url)

for element in resp.json()['threads']['product']['fullTitle']:
    print(element)
```

ERROR

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Usersname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Test.py", line 84, in script
    for element in resp.json()['threads']['product']['fullTitle']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Iterating through a dict always gives you just the keys. If you want everything, use `.items()`.

Comment: I dont think I can be able to make it - as I can see im having trouble to actually print out "fullTitle" through a for-loop.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to do. `fullTitle` is a element of the dictionary itself. If you just want that, why are you iterating? Just use `resp.json()['threads']['product']['fullTitle']`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have tried that and then im getting the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` - The thing is that I want to find all the fullTitle inside the Json.

Comment: *Where* do you get that? Show the code you are using and the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I edited the code where I now showed the code :)

Comment: Oh no I mean I want to find all the `FullTitle` that is inside the Json file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're iterating through the wrong thing. The list here is 'threads', each element of which has a 'product' dictionary which contains a 'fullTitle' element. So you iterate through that:

```
for thread in resp.json()['threads']
    print(thread['product']['fullTitle'])
```

Comment: This was the answer! I might been wrote the whole thread wrong but you indeed helped me out and I do really appreciate it!